# UISearchBar as UINavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem in Interface builder?

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

I know you can create a UISearchBar, put it in a UIBarButtonItem, and set that as the rightBarButtonItem in code, but I was wondering if there was a way to do that in IB now?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place an UIView inside UIBarButtonItem. You can then place any UIView subclass into that UIView as subview.